# CLLocationCoordinate2D and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-maps, geolocation

I have two NSMutableArray, first keeps some location's latitudes and second keeps longitudes. Then, I want to see this locations on map with markers. This code shows one point on map but I have several points at NSMutableArray. How can I do this? Is there anyone help me?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
span.longitudeDelta=0.2;


CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

location.latitude = 40.182533;
location.longitude = 29.066868;

region.span=span;
region.center=location;

if(addAnnotation != nil) {
    [mapView removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    [addAnnotation release];
    addAnnotation = nil;
}

addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
[mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create annotation for each lat-lon and add to the mapview. Assuming your lat lon array in balance and order the algorithm can go like below.

```
Loop through your lat or lon array

   CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

   location.latitude = latArray[index];
   location.longitude = lonArray[index];

   addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
   [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

Loop ends
```

Comment: I can not write current code as a comment but it is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790208/how-can-i-show-several-location-points-on-map-in-objective-c